# Preserve certain html tags during XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have looked up solutions on stackflow, but none of them seem to work for me. Here is my question. Lets say I have the following text :

Source:

```
<greatgrandparent>
<grandparent>
    <parent>
         <sibling>
              Hey, im the sibling .
          </sibling>
        <description>
        $300$ <br/> $250 <br/> $200! <br/> <p> Yes, that is right! <br/> You can own a ps3 for only $200 </p>
        </description>
    </parent>
    <parent>
         ... (SAME FORMAT)
    </parent>
       ... (Several more parents)
</grandparent>
</greatgrandparent>
```

Output:

```
 <newprice>
        $300$ <br/> $250 <br/> $200! <br/> Yes, that is right! <br/> You can own a ps3 for only $200  
    </newprice>
```

I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Current XSL:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="greatgrandparents">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "grandparent">

    <xsl:for-each select = "parent" >
          <newprice>
             <xsl:apply-templates>
           </newprice>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="description"> 
    <xsl:element name="newprice"> 
       <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="p"> 
   <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use templates to define behavior on specific elements

```
<!-- after standard identity template -->

<xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:element name="newprice">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template says to swap `description` with `newprice`. The second one says to ignore the `p` element.

If you're unfamiliar with the identity template, [take a look here](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity) for a few examples.

**EDIT**: Given the new example, we can see that you want to only extract the description element and its contents. Notice that the template action starts with the `match="/"` template. We can use this control where our stylesheet starts and thus skip much of the riffraff we want to filter out.

change the `<xsl:template match="/">` to something more like:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//description"/>   
        <!-- use a more specific XPath if you can -->
    </xsl:template>
```

So altogether our solution looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//description" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- this is the identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:element name="newprice">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Im going to give this a try. I'll let you know how it goes. I think I was having a problem with <xsl:apply-templates> It was for some weird reason adding other fields into all of this. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Using the identity template is key to `<xsl:apply-templates>` Let me know if you need a complete example or if this is enough.

Comment: ehh. I can't get it to work. It seems to be adding all the siblings of description.

Comment: the code given works for the example you provided. Is there something more we need to know?

Comment: i'm going to edit it just hold up a second. And thank you so much. Need this done soon, got a live presentation in June.

Comment: updated :). Sorry needed to remove some confidential stuff. Thanks :)

Comment: It's been updated. Notice that you only need four templates to get the desired result: The identity template, and the three I've shown you in this example.

Comment: Hmm, the <br> tag seems to be disappearing still.

Comment: The `<br />` tag will not copy unless you use The Identity Template.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the contents of  be inside a `CDATA` element? And then probably disable output encoding on xsl:value-of..

Comment: Thanks for the response! And I wasn't told that they need to be part of CDTATA from my supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [`xsl:copy-of`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp).

You would probably wind up with somthing like:

```
<xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Probably the shortest solution is this one**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="description">
   <newprice>
     <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
   </newprice>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::description)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, the wanted result is produced:**

```
<newprice>
        $300$ <br /> $250 <br /> $200! <br /> <p> Yes, that is right! <br /> You can own a ps3 for only $200 </p>
        </newprice>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>`** to copy all the subtree rooted in `description`, without the root itself.
2. **How we override (with a specific, *empty* template) the XSLT built-in template**, preventing any text nodes that are not descendents of a `<description>` element, to be output.